# $this is not getting accessed in a controller when called from a twig file

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to render meta tags by calling a controller named MetaController from a twig file.

```
<head>
    {{ render(controller('AppBundle:Meta:seoOptimizedMeta')) }}
```

The problem is when I try to access $this in the controller, I get blank pages. So, it seems the link to $this is lost when called from a twig file, so I wanted to know how am I supposed to get the $this pointer so as to carry out my database calling methods etc...

```
class MetaController extends Controller {
    public function seoOptimizedMetaAction()
    {
        $request = Request::createFromGlobals();
        $repo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Product');
        return new Response('<meta charset="UTF-8" />'); //testing
    }
}
```

For test sake,

```
class MetaController extends Controller {
    public function seoOptimizedMetaAction()
    {
        $request = Request::createFromGlobals();
        print_r($this);
        return new Response('<meta charset="UTF-8" />'); //testing
    }
}
```

The dev.log contains,

```
[2015-12-03 14:23:22] request.INFO: Matched route "homepage". {"route_parameters":{"_controller":"AppBundle\\Controller\\DefaultController::indexAction","_route":"homepage"},"request_uri":"http://localhost/mysnip/web/app_dev.php/"} []
[2015-12-03 14:23:22] security.INFO: Populated the TokenStorage with an anonymous Token. [] []
[2015-12-03 14:23:22] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DebugHandlersListener::configure". [] []
[2015-12-03 14:23:22] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2015-12-03 14:23:22] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DumpListener::configure". [] []
[2015-12-03 14:23:22] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\EventListener\SessionListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2015-12-03 14:23:22] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\FragmentListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2015-12-03 14:23:22] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2015-12-03 14:23:22] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2015-12-03 14:23:22] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\TranslatorListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2015-12-03 14:23:22] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2015-12-03 14:23:22] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\EventListener\RequestListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2015-12-03 14:23:22] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\DataCollector\RouterDataCollector::onKernelController". [] []
[2015-12-03 14:23:22] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DataCollector\RequestDataCollector::onKernelController". [] []
[2015-12-03 14:23:22] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ControllerListener::onKernelController". [] []
[2015-12-03 14:23:22] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ParamConverterListener::onKernelController". [] []
[2015-12-03 14:23:22] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\HttpCacheListener::onKernelController". [] []
[2015-12-03 14:23:22] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\SecurityListener::onKernelController". [] []
[2015-12-03 14:23:22] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\TemplateListener::onKernelController". [] []
[2015-12-03 14:23:22] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DebugHandlersListener::configure". [] []
[2015-12-03 14:23:22] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2015-12-03 14:23:22] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DumpListener::configure". [] []
[2015-12-03 14:23:22] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\EventListener\SessionListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2015-12-03 14:23:22] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\FragmentListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2015-12-03 14:23:22] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2015-12-03 14:23:22] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2015-12-03 14:23:22] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\TranslatorListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2015-12-03 14:23:22] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2015-12-03 14:23:22] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\EventListener\RequestListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2015-12-03 14:23:22] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\DataCollector\RouterDataCollector::onKernelController". [] []
[2015-12-03 14:23:22] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DataCollector\RequestDataCollector::onKernelController". [] []
[2015-12-03 14:23:22] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ControllerListener::onKernelController". [] []
[2015-12-03 14:23:22] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ParamConverterListener::onKernelController". [] []
[2015-12-03 14:23:22] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\HttpCacheListener::onKernelController". [] []
[2015-12-03 14:23:22] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\SecurityListener::onKernelController". [] []
[2015-12-03 14:23:22] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\TemplateListener::onKernelController". [] []
```

And a simple blank page in the browser!

Comment: $this pointer won't just disappear. If you have an object then non-static methods of this object have access to $this. Check the log files and see what error you're getting. It would help if you could also update the code with this line that uses $this and breaks the app.

Comment: I did check the log files, it doesn't show any error. It just logs the events called and then just displays a blank page, if you just remove the second line containing $this the app works again. just to test let's change $repo line to 
`print_r($this);`

Comment: Its definitely an error.

Comment: That line does alot more than just accessing `$this`. Is doctrine available? Is the repository available? Sidenote, don't create the request again. You can have it injected into the method by simply using `Request $request` in the method params.

Comment: What does the error log of your webserver show?

Comment: @Yoshi you also could just access the request by `$this->get('request');`

Comment: @KhorneHoly When using the service container, you should use [`request_stack`](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-4-the-request-stack).

Comment: @Yoshi Thanks, learned something new :)

Comment: I was looking for something like this!, As I wanted the previous routes to access meta descriptions from the data base.

Comment: It seems `Request::createFromGlobals` is disrupting the `$this`, but it was the way to get the master route, while `$this->get('request');` gave me a _fragment!

Answer (score 0):

1. I found out the problem of my error was my code, getting details of $this was probably too much for twig file to take in. So, print_r or var_dump should be strictly avoided.
2. You can also get the get the RequestStack by `$this->get('request_stack')`.

My problems have been solved, and thanks to @Yoshi for the suggestion.